# How to create dropdown that appear when a value is selected in a particular dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to create a dropdown with values: Monthly, Quarterly, Yearly, and the values that the user chooses those dropdown appear on the screen.

So my HTML is :

```
<div id="listmain" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1" onchange="show();">
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;listmain&#39;)">Select Criteria</span>
      <ul id="listmain_items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="main" value="month" id="month"><label for="month">Monthly </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="main" value="quarter" id="quarter"><label for="quarter">Quartely</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="main" value="year" id="year"><label for="year">Yearly</label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="1">
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list1&#39;)">Select Months</span>
      <ul id="list1_items" class="items" style="display: none;">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Apr-2021" id="apr"><label for="apr">April</label> </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="May-2021" id="may"><label for="may">May</label> </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jun-2021" id="jun"><label for="jun">June</label> </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jul-2021" id="jul"><label for="jul">July</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Aug-2021" id="aug"><label for="aug">August</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Sep-2021" id="sep"><label for="sep">September</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Oct-2021" id="oct"><label for="oct">October</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Nov-2021" id="nov"><label for="nov">November</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Dec-2021" id="dec"><label for="dec">December</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jan-2021" id="jan"><label for="jan">January</label> </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Feb-2021" id="feb"><label for="feb">February</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Mar-2021" id="mar"><label for="mar">March</label> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list2&#39;)">Select Quarter</span>
      <ul id="list2_items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter1" id="Q1"><label for="Q1">Apr - Jun (Quarter 1) </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter2" id="Q2"><label for="Q2">Jul - Sep (Quarter 2) </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter3" id="Q3"><label for="Q3">Oct - Dec (Quarter 3) </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter4" id="Q4"><label for="Q4">Jan - Mar (Quarter 4) </label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list3" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list3&#39;)">Select Monthly/Yearly</span>
      <ul id="list3_items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="April">6 Months </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="01">Year</li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="list4" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
      <span class="anchor" onclick="getElements(&#39;list4&#39;)">Select Year</span>
      <ul id="list4_items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2021">2021-2022 </li>
       <!--  <li><input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2021" />2021</li> --> 
      </ul>
    </div>
```

So I want to hide all of these and show a dropdown with checkbox of the following(Monthly,Quartely,Yearly) values and as the user selects from these, the particular dropdown appears.

Comment: And the attempt?

Comment: Tried this https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-select-box

Comment: Could you describe better what you want I don't get it..

Comment: So I want to hide all dropdowns except listmain and they appear as the value in listmain is selected as in if monthly value is selected it should show list1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <div>
    <select>
        <option value="criteria">Select Criteria</option>
        <option value="quarter">Select Quarter</option>
        <option value="monthly">Select Monthly/Yearly</option>
        <option value="year">Select Year</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="criteria box">
    <ul id="listmain_items" class="items">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="main" value="month" id="month">
        <label for="month">Monthly </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="main" value="quarter" id="quarter">
        <label for="quarter">Quartely</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="main" value="year" id="year">
        <label for="year">Yearly</label></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="quarter box">
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter1" id="Q1"> 
        <label for="Q1">Apr - Jun (Quarter 1) </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter2" id="Q2"> 
        <label for="Q2">Jul - Sep (Quarter 2) </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter3" id="Q3"> 
        <label for="Q3">Oct - Dec (Quarter 3) </label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="quarter" value="Quarter4" id="Q4"> 
        <label for="Q4">Jan - Mar (Quarter 4) </label></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
    
  <div class="monthly box">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Apr-2021" id="apr"> 
      <label for="apr">April</label> </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="May-2021" id="may"> 
      <label for="may">May</label> </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jun-2021" id="jun"> 
      <label for="jun">June</label> </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jul-2021" id="jul"> 
      <label for="jul">July</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Aug-2021" id="aug"> 
      <label for="aug">August</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Sep-2021" id="sep"> 
      <label for="sep">September</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Oct-2021" id="oct"> 
      <label for="oct">October</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Nov-2021" id="nov"> 
      <label for="nov">November</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Dec-2021" id="dec"> 
      <label for="dec">December</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Jan-2021" id="jan"> 
      <label for="jan">January</label> </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Feb-2021" id="feb"> 
      <label for="feb">February</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="month" value="Mar-2021" id="mar"> 
      <label for="mar">March</label> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="year box">
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="6-months">6 Months </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="year">Year</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2021">2021-2022 </li>
     <li><input type="checkbox" name="year" value="2021" />2021</li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
```